# Querying Attribute Properties for dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore (Not so easy)

Tags: javascript, tree, dojo

I have a dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore object with items which contain a 'children' attribute, which in turn contains an array of children items. I'm storing a tree, and I need to fetch the leaf nodes from this tree. I have written a fetch method but it will not work giving it a query of "children: []" How can I fetch the data store items that have a children.length of 0 (the leaf nodes)? A blank array without adding attributes such as 'leaf' : bool to my items would obviously work, but I'd rather not have the extra attribute.

```
dojo.require(dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore);

// A tree node with no children, these are the kind I want returned
// from the query!
var rootItem = {
        children: []
};

var treeStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
    data: {
        items: [rootItem]
    }
}); 

//when dojo reaches one of its inner filtering methods
//there is a point where it calls dojo.some() to see
//which elements in the array to return which match the
//given items attribute, this is where it fails

treeStore.fetch({
    query: {children: []},
    queryOptions: {deep: true},
    onComplete: function(leafItems) {
        // All the items with no children here...
    }
});
```

I also tried nesting a function for the attribute to no avail:

```
treeStore.fetch({
    query: {
        children: function(store, item){
                return store.getValue(item, 'children').length == 0;
        }
    },
    queryOptions: {deep: true},
    onComplete: function(leafItems) {
        // All the items with no children here...
    }
});
```

Comment: I am not too big on hierarchical data in data stores, but supposedly the Dojo data stores support hierarchical data.  You must turn on the hierarchical option or something.  Google it and you'll find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
baseStore.fetch({
                query:{id:'*'},
                onComplete:function(a,b,c){
                    dojo.forEach(a,function(item,index){
                        console.log(item.children);
                    })
                }
            })
```

if item.children is undefined then those are the "item" that you want.
If you don't want to use a separate fetch for this operation alone, then use a private property called _arrayOfAllItems on the store to get a flat data store, upon which you can do the same condition mentioned above.

Comment: This is the  only solution I could think of too.